# Cython: passing pointer to pointer in a function taking void **

Tags: c, pointers, cython

I am trying to write a function that under certain conditions, changes a pointer to a structure to point to a different structure.

My constraint is that I want to retain the initial function signature that takes a generic pointer to a pointer (not to a specific structure type) as an argument.

This won't work:

```
[nav] In [5]: %%cython -f 
         ...: ctypedef struct A: 
         ...:     int x 
         ...:     int y 
         ...:  
         ...: cdef fn(void **m): 
         ...:     # Arbitrary code that changes m[0] to point to another structure
         ...:     pass
         ...:      
         ...: cdef A a 
         ...: cdef A *ap = &a 
         ...: a.x = 2 
         ...: a.y = 3 
         ...: print(ap.x) 
         ...: fn(&ap) 
         ...: print(ap.x) 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef A a
cdef A *ap = &a
a.x = 2
a.y = 3
print(a.x)
fn(&ap)
  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/home/me/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_3c3902694eafae18c66cb761d4a6b210.pyx:20:3: Cannot assign type 'A **' to 'void **'
```

I guess that is because even if I can write a function that takes a `void *` as an argument and automatically casts any passed pointer to a `void *`, that won't work with a pointer to a void pointer, is that correct?

If so, how do I pass my structure pointer pointer so that `ap` can point to a different structure?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Upon further reading I realized that this is a C architecture "feature". [This useful article](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html) gives some brief explanation:

> One side point about pointers to pointers and memory allocation: although the `void *` type, as returned by `malloc`, is a "generic pointer", suitable for assigning to or from pointers of any type, the hypothetical type `void **` is not a "generic pointer to pointer." Our `allocstr` example can only be used for allocating pointers to char. It would not be possible to use a function which returned generic pointers indirectly via a `void **` pointer, because when you tried to use it, for example by declaring and calling

```
double *dptr;
if(!hypotheticalwrapperfunc(100, sizeof(double), &dptr))
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
```

> you would not be passing a `void **`, but rather a `double **`.

I gather that at this point what I can do is to either specify the data type in my function signature, or return the new assigned value?

Comment: Specifying the value is probably best. You might also be able to use a macro rather than a function since they're expanded in place and don't need the type of arguments specified - you'd wrap it in Cython by pretending that it's a function with varargs `void fn(...)` to override Cython's attempt to understand the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by passing what the function asks for, i.e. a `void **`, then casting it when I need it:

```
[nav] In [5]: %%cython -f 
         ...: ctypedef struct A: 
         ...:     int x 
         ...:     int y 
         ...:  
         ...: cdef fn(void **m): 
         ...:     # Arbitrary code that changes m[0] to point to another structure
         ...:     pass
         ...:      
         ...: cdef A a 
         ...: cdef void *avp = <void *>&a
         ...: cdef A *ap = <A*>avp
         ...: a.x = 2 
         ...: a.y = 3 
         ...: print(ap.x) 
         ...: fn(&ap)
         ...: ap = <A*>avp # Must reassign
         ...: print(ap.x)
```